# Is it possible to output a WEB constant with a TeX (or WEB) command?

Tags: tex-core, web

`tex.web` defines several constants which are changed at compile time.

How can I get the values of the current TeX or eTeX instance?

I'm about to put a TeX or eTeX  generated by web2js [Jim Fowler's WEB/TeX Pascal to WebAssembly compiler](https://github.com/kisonecat/web2js) into operation and have memory management problems of other than only plain formats. How can I get the values I'm looking for from my existing Tex Live 2019 (windows 10) distribution?

I have to store these values in `tex.sys` or `etex.sys` for compilation with web2js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most of the ones that you can normally set in texmf.cnf are shown at the end of the log

If I run

```
tex \\tracingstats=1 \\bye
```

the log shows

```
$ more texput.log 
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=tex 2019.7.26)
  1 AUG 2019 18:56
**\tracingstats=1 \bye

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1 string out of 497973
 10 string characters out of 6220659
 5898 words of memory out of 5000000
 926 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 14794 words of font info for 50 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 1i,0n,0p,1b,6s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
```

Comment: According to output statistics in `tex.web`: **string:** `max_strings - init_str_ptr` **string characters:**  `pool_size - init_pool_ptr` **words:** `mem_end+1 - mem_min` **multiletter:** `hash_size` **words of font info** `font_mem_size` **fonts:** `font_max - font_base` **hyhenation:** `hyph_size` **i:** `stack_size` **n:** `nest_size` **p:** `param_size` **b:** `buf_size` **s:** `save_size` . What about: 
string_vacancies, trie_size, trie_op_size, dvi_buf_size, file_name_size,
mem_bot, mem_top, hash_prime, min_quarterword, max_quarterword, min_halfword, max_halfword.

Comment: which limit have you reached? I don't think you can access them from within tex for compatibility reasons texlive's tex.ch sets larger values than tex.web 

% max_quarterword without changing the memoryword structure in `texmfmem.h'.
@x [8.110] l.2422 - increase |max_halfword|
@d min_halfword==0 {smallest allowable value in a |halfword|}
@d max_halfword==65535 {largest allowable value in a |halfword|}
@y 2424
@d min_halfword==-@"FFFFFFF {smallest allowable value in a |halfword|}
@d max_halfword==@"FFFFFFF {largest allowable value in a |halfword|}
@z

Comment: I will look into `tex.ch`, mix a new version of my `tex.sys` based on this information here. Then I'll get back.

Comment: The first follow-up question: [TeX initex error “TeX capacity exceeded, sorry "pool size=8563” while constant pool_size is set to 350000. What can I do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502509/tex-initex-error-tex-capacity-exceeded-sorry-pool-size-8563-while-constant).