# TeX initex error "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [pool size=8563]" while constant pool_size is set to 350000. What can I do?

Tags: tex-core, web

**Attention**: This TeX is generated by **web2js** [Jim Fowler's WEB/TeX Pascal to WebAssembly compiler](https://github.com/kisonecat/web2js).

This is a follow-up question to [Is it possible to output a WEB constant with a TeX (or WEB) command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502450/is-it-possible-to-output-a-web-constant-with-a-tex-or-web-command).

I get this error in `lplain.log` when I try to dump the lplain format.

```
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (INITEX)  4 JUL 1776 12:00
**lplain.tex \dump
(lplain.tex Preloading the plain format: codes, registers,! 
...
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [pool size=8563].
l.4015 \let\
            @accii=\`
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.
```

But the pool_size constant is set to 350000 (default value: 32000).

Here's my used tex.sys (no use of tex.ch):

```
eTeX compatible constants for web2js

@x
@<Constants...@>=
@!mem_max=30000; {greatest index in \TeX's internal |mem| array;
  must be strictly less than |max_halfword|;
  must be equal to |mem_top| in \.{INITEX}, otherwise |>=mem_top|}
@!mem_min=0; {smallest index in \TeX's internal |mem| array;
  must be |min_halfword| or more;
  must be equal to |mem_bot| in \.{INITEX}, otherwise |<=mem_bot|}
@!buf_size=500; {maximum number of characters simultaneously present in
  current lines of open files and in control sequences between
  \.{\\csname} and \.{\\endcsname}; must not exceed |max_halfword|}
@!error_line=72; {width of context lines on terminal error messages}
@!half_error_line=42; {width of first lines of contexts in terminal
  error messages; should be between 30 and |error_line-15|}
@!max_print_line=79; {width of longest text lines output; should be at least 60}
@!stack_size=200; {maximum number of simultaneous input sources}
@!max_in_open=6; {maximum number of input files and error insertions that
  can be going on simultaneously}
@!font_max=75; {maximum internal font number; must not exceed |max_quarterword|
  and must be at most |font_base+256|}
@!font_mem_size=20000; {number of words of |font_info| for all fonts}
@!param_size=60; {maximum number of simultaneous macro parameters}
@!nest_size=40; {maximum number of semantic levels simultaneously active}
@!max_strings=3000; {maximum number of strings; must not exceed |max_halfword|}
@!string_vacancies=8000; {the minimum number of characters that should be
  available for the user's control sequences and font names,
  after \TeX's own error messages are stored}
@!pool_size=32000; {maximum number of characters in strings, including all
  error messages and help texts, and the names of all fonts and
  control sequences; must exceed |string_vacancies| by the total
  length of \TeX's own strings, which is currently about 23000}
@!save_size=600; {space for saving values outside of current group; must be
  at most |max_halfword|}
@!trie_size=8000; {space for hyphenation patterns; should be larger for
  \.{INITEX} than it is in production versions of \TeX}
@!trie_op_size=500; {space for ``opcodes'' in the hyphenation patterns}
@!dvi_buf_size=800; {size of the output buffer; must be a multiple of 8}
@!file_name_size=40; {file names shouldn't be longer than this}
@!pool_name='TeXformats:TEX.POOL                     ';
  {string of length |file_name_size|; tells where the string pool appears}
@.TeXformats@>

@ Like the preceding parameters, the following quantities can be changed
at compile time to extend or reduce \TeX's capacity. But if they are changed,
it is necessary to rerun the initialization program \.{INITEX}
@.INITEX@>
to generate new tables for the production \TeX\ program.
One can't simply make helter-skelter changes to the following constants,
since certain rather complex initialization
numbers are computed from them. They are defined here using
\.{WEB} macros, instead of being put into \PASCAL's |const| list, in order to
emphasize this distinction.

@d mem_bot=0 {smallest index in the |mem| array dumped by \.{INITEX};
  must not be less than |mem_min|}
@d mem_top==30000 {largest index in the |mem| array dumped by \.{INITEX};
  must be substantially larger than |mem_bot|
  and not greater than |mem_max|}
@y
@<Constants...@>=
@!mem_max=200000; {greatest index in \TeX's internal |mem| array;
  must be strictly less than |max_halfword|;
  must be equal to |mem_top| in \.{INITEX}, otherwise |>=mem_top|}
@!mem_min=0; {smallest index in \TeX's internal |mem| array;
  must be |min_halfword| or more;
  must be equal to |mem_bot| in \.{INITEX}, otherwise |<=mem_bot|}
@!buf_size=5000; {maximum number of characters simultaneously present in
  current lines of open files and in control sequences between
  \.{\\csname} and \.{\\endcsname}; must not exceed |max_halfword|}
@!error_line=72; {width of context lines on terminal error messages}
@!half_error_line=42; {width of first lines of contexts in terminal
  error messages; should be between 30 and |error_line-15|}
@!max_print_line=79; {width of longest text lines output; should be at least 60}
@!stack_size=1000; {maximum number of simultaneous input sources}
@!max_in_open=6; {maximum number of input files and error insertions that
  can be going on simultaneously}
@!font_max=75; {maximum internal font number; must not exceed |max_quarterword|
  and must be at most |font_base+256|}
@!font_mem_size=20000; {number of words of |font_info| for all fonts}
@!param_size=60; {maximum number of simultaneous macro parameters}
@!nest_size=40; {maximum number of semantic levels simultaneously active}
@!max_strings=60000; {maximum number of strings; must not exceed |max_halfword|}
@!string_vacancies=300000; {the minimum number of characters that should be
  available for the user's control sequences and font names,
  after \TeX's own error messages are stored}
@!pool_size=350000; {maximum number of characters in strings, including all
  error messages and help texts, and the names of all fonts and
  control sequences; must exceed |string_vacancies| by the total
  length of \TeX's own strings, which is currently about 23000}
@!save_size=600; {space for saving values outside of current group; must be
  at most |max_halfword|}
@!trie_size=8000; {space for hyphenation patterns; should be larger for
  \.{INITEX} than it is in production versions of \TeX}
@!trie_op_size=500; {space for ``opcodes'' in the hyphenation patterns}
@!dvi_buf_size=800; {size of the output buffer; must be a multiple of 8}
@!file_name_size=40; {file names shouldn't be longer than this}
@!pool_name='TeXformats:TEX.POOL                     ';
  {string of length |file_name_size|; tells where the string pool appears}
@.TeXformats@>

@ Like the preceding parameters, the following quantities can be changed
at compile time to extend or reduce \TeX's capacity. But if they are changed,
it is necessary to rerun the initialization program \.{INITEX}
@.INITEX@>
to generate new tables for the production \TeX\ program.
One can't simply make helter-skelter changes to the following constants,
since certain rather complex initialization
numbers are computed from them. They are defined here using
\.{WEB} macros, instead of being put into \PASCAL's |const| list, in order to
emphasize this distinction.

@d mem_bot=0 {smallest index in the |mem| array dumped by \.{INITEX};
  must not be less than |mem_min|}
@d mem_top==200000 {largest index in the |mem| array dumped by \.{INITEX};
  must be substantially larger than |mem_bot|
  and not greater than |mem_max|}
@z

@x
@d min_quarterword=0 {smallest allowable value in a |quarterword|}
@d max_quarterword=255 {largest allowable value in a |quarterword|}
@d min_halfword==0 {smallest allowable value in a |halfword|}
@d max_halfword==65535 {largest allowable value in a |halfword|}
@y
@d min_quarterword=0 {smallest allowable value in a |quarterword|}
@d max_quarterword=255 {largest allowable value in a |quarterword|}
@d min_halfword==0 {smallest allowable value in a |halfword|}
@d max_halfword==16777215 {largest allowable value in a |halfword|}
@z
```

Comment: My impression is that your attempt to compile TeX didn't go very well: July 4, 1776 is not the current date.

Comment: @egreg According to ShreevatsaR **4 Jul 1776 12:00** is just a default that Knuth left in tex.web for system-dependent changes to replace with a function for getting current date and time. I will report this issue to Jim Fowler's git web2js.

Comment: tex.ch sets some other pool related values, but to be honest I don't immediately see where they are used @!inf_pool_size = 32000;
@!sup_pool_size = 40000000;
@!inf_pool_free = 1000;
@!sup_pool_free = sup_pool_size;
@!inf_string_vacancies = 8000;
@!sup_string_vacancies = sup_pool_size - 23000;

@!sup_hash_extra = sup_max_strings;
@!inf_hash_extra = 0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I was successful with the following `TeX_big.sys`:**

*With a `lplaint.tex` format i.e. LaTeX 2.09 the TeX_big system uses approx. 350 pages of memory i.e. approx. 1.4 MB of memory.*

```
% this is tex_big.sys 
% eTeX compatible constants for web2js

% https://www.cv.nrao.edu/~abridle/toolmemo/miktex_manual.pdf
% explanated options from page 30 
% global.pages in dt_global.js = 1000 

% changes Fr, 02.08.2019 according to mainbody.h


% https://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/runtimeparams.html
% ✓ main_memory   =2000000        % /1024/1024 => approx. 2 MB  
% ✓ extra_mem_bot =2000000 
% ✓ font_mem_size =2000000 
% main_memory:        Total words of memory available, for TeX, METAFONT, and MetaPost. 
% in DEK terms:       "main memory size" = mem_max+1-mem_min; mem_min must be 0 or more 
% extra_mem_bot:      Extra space for large TeX data structures: boxes, glue, breakpoints, et al.
% font_mem_size:      Words of font info available for TeX
% it concerns array sizes!

% https://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/texmfdefaults.html
% https://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/texdefaults.html
% other default values !!


% ✅ @d max_quarterword =  65535 {largest allowable value in a |quarterword|}
% ✅ @d min_halfword    ==-1073741823 {smallest allowable value in a |halfword|}
% ✅ @d max_halfword    ==1073741823 {largest allowable value in a |halfword|}
% halfword 3FFFFFFF can address 1024 MByte i.e. 1 GB of memory 

% - bigger codepage for UTF-8 input (chi-problem)
% Marcel Krüger 26.07.2019 StackExchange TeX
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/501647/192681
% UTF-8 bigger codepage

% Marcel Krüger 17.07.2019 StackExchange TeX 
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500402/192681



@x
@<Constants...@>=
@!mem_max=30000; {greatest index in \TeX's internal |mem| array;
  must be strictly less than |max_halfword|;
  must be equal to |mem_top| in \.{INITEX}, otherwise |>=mem_top|}
@!mem_min=0; {smallest index in \TeX's internal |mem| array;
  must be |min_halfword| or more;
  must be equal to |mem_bot| in \.{INITEX}, otherwise |<=mem_bot|}
@!buf_size=500; {maximum number of characters simultaneously present in
  current lines of open files and in control sequences between
  \.{\\csname} and \.{\\endcsname}; must not exceed |max_halfword|}
@!error_line=72; {width of context lines on terminal error messages}
@!half_error_line=42; {width of first lines of contexts in terminal
  error messages; should be between 30 and |error_line-15|}
@!max_print_line=79; {width of longest text lines output; should be at least 60}
@!stack_size=200; {maximum number of simultaneous input sources}
@!max_in_open=6; {maximum number of input files and error insertions that
  can be going on simultaneously}
@!font_max=75; {maximum internal font number; must not exceed |max_quarterword|
  and must be at most |font_base+256|}
@!font_mem_size=20000; {number of words of |font_info| for all fonts}
@!param_size=60; {maximum number of simultaneous macro parameters}
@!nest_size=40; {maximum number of semantic levels simultaneously active}
@!max_strings=3000; {maximum number of strings; must not exceed |max_halfword|}
@!string_vacancies=8000; {the minimum number of characters that should be
  available for the user's control sequences and font names,
  after \TeX's own error messages are stored}
@!pool_size=32000; {maximum number of characters in strings, including all
  error messages and help texts, and the names of all fonts and
  control sequences; must exceed |string_vacancies| by the total
  length of \TeX's own strings, which is currently about 23000}
@!save_size=600; {space for saving values outside of current group; must be
  at most |max_halfword|}
@!trie_size=8000; {space for hyphenation patterns; should be larger for
  \.{INITEX} than it is in production versions of \TeX}
@!trie_op_size=500; {space for ``opcodes'' in the hyphenation patterns}
@!dvi_buf_size=800; {size of the output buffer; must be a multiple of 8}
@!file_name_size=40; {file names shouldn't be longer than this}
@!pool_name='TeXformats:TEX.POOL                     ';
  {string of length |file_name_size|; tells where the string pool appears}
@.TeXformats@>

@ Like the preceding parameters, the following quantities can be changed
at compile time to extend or reduce \TeX's capacity. But if they are changed,
it is necessary to rerun the initialization program \.{INITEX}
@.INITEX@>
to generate new tables for the production \TeX\ program.
One can't simply make helter-skelter changes to the following constants,
since certain rather complex initialization
numbers are computed from them. They are defined here using
\.{WEB} macros, instead of being put into \PASCAL's |const| list, in order to
emphasize this distinction.

@d mem_bot=0 {smallest index in the |mem| array dumped by \.{INITEX};
  must not be less than |mem_min|}
@d mem_top==30000 {largest index in the |mem| array dumped by \.{INITEX};
  must be substantially larger than |mem_bot|
  and not greater than |mem_max|}
@y
@<Constants...@>=
@!mem_max=2000000; {greatest index in \TeX's internal |mem| array;
  must be strictly less than |max_halfword|;
  must be equal to |mem_top| in \.{INITEX}, otherwise |>=mem_top|}
@!mem_min=0; {smallest index in \TeX's internal |mem| array;
  must be |min_halfword| or more;
  must be equal to |mem_bot| in \.{INITEX}, otherwise |<=mem_bot|}
@!buf_size=5000; {maximum number of characters simultaneously present in
  current lines of open files and in control sequences between
  \.{\\csname} and \.{\\endcsname}; must not exceed |max_halfword|}
@!error_line=72; {width of context lines on terminal error messages}
@!half_error_line=42; {width of first lines of contexts in terminal
  error messages; should be between 30 and |error_line-15|}
@!max_print_line=79; {width of longest text lines output; should be at least 60}
@!stack_size=1000; {maximum number of simultaneous input sources}
@!max_in_open=6; {maximum number of input files and error insertions that
  can be going on simultaneously}
@!font_max=75; {maximum internal font number; must not exceed |max_quarterword|
  and must be at most |font_base+256|}
@!font_mem_size=2000000; {number of words of |font_info| for all fonts}
@!param_size=60; {maximum number of simultaneous macro parameters}
@!nest_size=40; {maximum number of semantic levels simultaneously active}
@!max_strings=60000; {maximum number of strings; must not exceed |max_halfword|}
@!string_vacancies=300000; {the minimum number of characters that should be
  available for the user's control sequences and font names,
  after \TeX's own error messages are stored}
@!pool_size=350000; {maximum number of characters in strings, including all
  error messages and help texts, and the names of all fonts and
  control sequences; must exceed |string_vacancies| by the total
  length of \TeX's own strings, which is currently about 23000}
@!save_size=600; {space for saving values outside of current group; must be
  at most |max_halfword|}
@!trie_size=8000; {space for hyphenation patterns; should be larger for
  \.{INITEX} than it is in production versions of \TeX}
@!trie_op_size=500; {space for ``opcodes'' in the hyphenation patterns}
@!dvi_buf_size=800; {size of the output buffer; must be a multiple of 8}
@!file_name_size=40; {file names shouldn't be longer than this}
@!pool_name='TeXformats:TEX.POOL                     ';
  {string of length |file_name_size|; tells where the string pool appears}
@.TeXformats@>

@ Like the preceding parameters, the following quantities can be changed
at compile time to extend or reduce \TeX's capacity. But if they are changed,
it is necessary to rerun the initialization program \.{INITEX}
@.INITEX@>
to generate new tables for the production \TeX\ program.
One can't simply make helter-skelter changes to the following constants,
since certain rather complex initialization
numbers are computed from them. They are defined here using
\.{WEB} macros, instead of being put into \PASCAL's |const| list, in order to
emphasize this distinction.

@d mem_bot=0 {smallest index in the |mem| array dumped by \.{INITEX};
  must not be less than |mem_min|}
@d mem_top==2000000 {largest index in the |mem| array dumped by \.{INITEX};
  must be substantially larger than |mem_bot|
  and not greater than |mem_max|}
@z


@x
for i:=0 to @'37 do xchr[i]:=' ';
for i:=@'177 to @'377 do xchr[i]:=' ';
@y
for i:=0 to @'37 do xchr[i]:=chr(i);
for i:=@'177 to @'377 do xchr[i]:=chr(i);
@z



@x
@d min_quarterword=0 {smallest allowable value in a |quarterword|}
@d max_quarterword=255 {largest allowable value in a |quarterword|}
@d min_halfword==0 {smallest allowable value in a |halfword|}
@d max_halfword==65535 {largest allowable value in a |halfword|}
@y
@d min_quarterword=0 {smallest allowable value in a |quarterword|}
@d max_quarterword=65535 {largest allowable value in a |quarterword|}
@d min_halfword==-1073741823 {smallest allowable value in a |halfword|}
@d max_halfword==1073741823 {largest allowable value in a |halfword|}
@z
```